# How can I do my calculation more efficiently?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

```
ClearAll
α = 19*10^-6;
T = 300;
T0 = 300;
r0 = 400*10^-6;
λ = 700*10^-9;
L = 5;
rf = r0 *Sqrt[1 + 2*α (T - T0)] 
Dabertura = 2*rf
(* Sin[θ]=1.22*λ/Dabertura *)
(* Sin[θ]~Tan[θ]=(Dfigura/2)/L=Dfigura/(2L) *)
Dabertura = 2*L*1.22*λ/Dabertura 
Dfigura = (2*L*1.22*λ/Dabertura)*(10^2)

ClearAll
α = 19*10^-6;
r0 = 400*10^-6;
λ = 650*10^-9; 
L = 5;
rf = r0*Sqrt[1 + 2*α*ΔT];
Dabertura = 2*rf;
(*Sin[θ]=1.22*λ/Dabertura*)
(*\Sin[θ]~Tan[θ]=(Dfigura/2)/L=Dfigura/(2L)*)
Dfigura = (2*L*1.22*λ/Dabertura)*100;

Plot[Dfigura, {ΔT, 0, 300}]

ClearAll
Vi = 0.991233; (* initial graph value *)
Vf = 0.985649;(* final graph value *)
Vp = Abs[Vf - Vi]/Vi*100*Vf
```

This is the program I did.
For each analysis I keep `α,` T, T0, L` values constant, and I need to vary the other parameters.

As in the example in the program, I need to vary `λ` from $500
\times 10^{-9}$ to $750\times 10^{-9}$ and $r0$ from $10^{-5}$ to $10^{-3}$.

Soon after I create a graph, and analyze the percentage variation of the initial and final values of the parameters I chose.

I want to know if there is a way to optimize the program so that I don't have to change the value every time I calculate with a new `λ` and a new `r0`.

And also if you have some way to calculate the percentage variation without having to click on the graph and looking at the values to put in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

See if the following code does what you seek. I chose the pitch over each range arbitrarily since you did not specify it. `output` is a list of triplet including $(\lambda, r_0, \%_{difference})$:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

α = 19*10^-6;
L = 5;
rf = r0*Sqrt[1 + 2*α*ΔT];
Dabertura = 2*rf;
Dfigura = (2*L*1.22*λ/Dabertura)*100;

output = Flatten[
 Table[
  {λ, r0, Abs[Subtract[##]]/#1*100*#2 & @@ (Dfigura /. ΔT -> {0, 300})},
  {λ, 500.*^-9, 750*^-9, 10*^-9},
  {r0, PowerRange[1.*^-5, 1*^-3, 2]}
  ],
 1
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write a function, say `f`, that takes `λ` and `r0` as arguments and makes a plot of a simplified version of the expression you call `Dfigura` over the  domain `{T0, T}`. Like so:

```
With[{α = 19*^-6, T = 300, T0 = 0, L = 5},
  f[λ_, r0_] := 
    Plot[2.44*^2 λ L/(r0 Sqrt[1 + 2 α t]), {t, T0, T}, 
      PlotLabel -> Row[{"λ: ", N@λ, "  r0: ", N@r0}]]]
```

Note how much your code can be simplified.

To make the whole set of plots you describe, do this:

```
Multicolumn[
  Flatten[
    Table[f[λ, r0], {λ, 5*^-7, 7.5*^-7, .5*^-7}, {r0, PowerRange[1*^-5, 1*^-3]}]], 
  6]
```

[image: plots]

As shown above, this produces 18 plots. The plots look linear but they are not. The apparent linearity is a purely visual effect caused by the range of the expression being very small in the domain `{0, 300}`.